# "Mail sending denied"

Tags: asp.net, email, azure, smtp, gmail

I'm using as SMTP server for my domain.

I created a "Contact-us" page that a user will be able to send emails to the company from.

When I'm sending the email from my computer it works, but people complain to me that when they're sending emails they get the following message:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.0 Mail sending denied abcdefghi
```

[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bCLI.jpg)

Here are my settings,

**Web.config:**

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="info@company.com">
      <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587"
        userName="info@company.com" password="mypassword" enableSsl="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Contact(ContactFormModel contact)
{
  ViewBag.Message = false;
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var message = new MailMessage();
    var sender = new MailAddress(contact.Email, contact.FullName);
    message.Sender = sender;
    message.From = sender;
    message.To.Add(Settings.Default.ContactUsEmail);
    if (contact.SendSelfCopy)
      message.CC.Add(sender);
    message.ReplyToList.Add(sender);

    message.Subject = string.Format("Company Website - Msg from {0}: {1}",
      contact.FullName, contact.Subject);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("From: <a href='mailto:{1}'>{0}</a>: <b>{2}</b><hr/>",
      sender.DisplayName, sender.Address, contact.Subject);
    sb.AppendLine(contact.Message);
    message.Body = sb.ToString();
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
      client.Timeout = 15000;

      try
      {
        client.Send(message);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }

    ModelState.Clear();
    ViewBag.Success = true;
    ViewBag.Message = Settings.Default.ContactUsSuccessMessage;
    return View();
  }

  return View(contact);
}
```

The website is hosted in Windows Azure and runs with .NET 4.5.

Comment: When you send from your computer, is the "from" the same email address as your SMTP credentials? Just thinking maybe Gmail doesn't like you logging in then sending email as someone else.

Comment: No, the 'from' is different than the actual mail box. I even tried sending the email from a private browsing instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue when trying to send emails through Azure.

The problem here is that Google does not trust the IP address of your deployment.  The short fix for this is to remote into your web role and log into Gmail with the account you are trying to use.

I have also fixed this by logging into the Gmail account from my local machine and clicking "trust connection" for the IP address of the web role.

You should keep in mind, however, that you will have to do this every time you get a new IP address when Azure decides to bounce your deployment.

On my application, I just ended up connecting to the SMTP server on my clent's corp network.  If that is not an option, you might try [SendGrid](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/).

Comment: Can you please explain your last note about connection to SMTP on client? I didn't understand it.

Comment: @Shimmy sorry for not being clearer.  I was talking about a client company (I'm a consultant) not a client machine.  The company I am at has an SMTP server sitting on premise.  We connected to it from Azure through their firewall to send emails.

Comment: I liked the SendGrid idea, but unfortunately the Azure store is not available if you didn't sign up from the USA! [Check it out](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/store-sign-up-restrictions/).